# Downvotes that can give the wrong impression

Tags: discussion, comments, policy, voting

Downvotes without comments can give the wrong impression. The reason on this site for downvotes is varied. One does not agree to the answer. One does not understand it. Others may not understand it. It doesnt answer the question exactly. There is a better answer. I am sure there are many more. My question is that downvotes which are not for the first reason that one doesnt agree with the answer can give the wrong impression that the downvoter thinks the answer is wrong halachically or if not wrong not too bad if done. So at least he should mention  in a comment that he agrees with it but has downvoted it for other reasons if he doesnt give them.

In a recent answer of mine containing both English and Hebrew I included in the English that pre-marital sex was wrong. As it happens that was almost the main part. This was downvoted with no reason given. Since then a girl has written a comment providing her website where she almost prides herself with pre-marital sex and certainly thinks its muttar the way she does it by going to the mikva first. This comment is still there for others to follow in her footsteps.

Who knows how many others have also reached the wrong impression from your downvote. Instead of forcefully saying in a comment that it was totally wrong to have pre-marital sex and dissuading others from having it, the opposite has occurred. A heter has been given on condition one went to the mikva first.This can still be rectified if you can bring yourselves to agree with what I am saying which can be very difficult.

(If a girl practicing pre marital sex and has a blog allowing it and even teaching others how to do it by telling them how to go to mikva pretending to be married. This blog should not be allowed to be linked or mentioned on here. In other words her blog name has to be deleted.)

I have written on her post but since it is moderated it is unlikely to be approved.

**What change I want:**

A downvote on a halacha for whatever reason, has to have a comment saying that they agree with what is written meaning the halacha but they have downvoted for other reasons.

Comment: Are you suggesting the downvote to your post made this woman decide to have premarital sex, and moreover that many others may now follow in her footsteps?? You've got to be kidding. That's preposterous! Her blog even started before your post was written.

Comment: I don't see either a question or a clear proposal here. Please [edit] this post to make it clear either what information you want or what change in site mechanics, site policy, or community behavior you are requesting.

Comment: This downvote gave a heter to this woman and who knows to how many others who will now be reading her blog.

Comment: Chas v'shalom that this community would cause someone to sin! This is very serious. In order to be responsible, then, I recommend that we're each mindful not to post off-topic responses and ensure that we are cogent and clear and are therefore provide answers that are not going to be down-voted.  This has a side benefit of not making people waste their time reading, trying to parse, and editing hastily-written responses or getting bogged down discussing "politics" here in meta or chat.

Comment: I have now said what changes I wanted. I hope i have made them clear.

Comment: Why do you edit it. I mean the second thing as much as the first

Comment: @shulem, One question/proposal per question. Based on your title, it's clear that the one I left as your conclusion is your primary proposal here. If you want to give the other proposal equal weight, I recommend that you post it as a separate Meta question. However, that may be inadvisable for an individual comment that you don't like, due to the "[Streisand Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect)." Perhaps you should just flag the comment.

Comment: Dont come with stupid rules of one proposal per question. We are talking something serious where rules should not be applied. If a fire is burning you dont work to rule.

Comment: @shulem I disagree http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/25932/759

Comment: It is not an individual comment I dont like. It is the policy here of not deleting such comments. I dont know the girl It is nothing personal as you try to make out.

Comment: @shulem, If you're trying to change site policy in general, then all the more so that you should make a cogent, independent case for it. Censorship of comments has nothing to do with downvote policy.

Comment: @shulem, if you want to reply to her comment, why not reply to her comment, instead of obsessing over the narishkeit that is votes on your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You propose:

> A downvote on a halacha for whatever reason, has to have a comment saying that they agree with what is written meaning the halacha but they have downvoted for other reasons.

The tooltip over the voting-down button reads "This answer is not useful". More detail is at [Stack Exchange's description of the downvote](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-down):

> #### When should I vote down?
>
> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

So downvotes are for both *sloppy* posts and *wrong* posts. There is IMO real concern that, when someone sees a downvote on a *halacha*-related post, he will assume the downvote is for the latter reason. What you propose is one solution to this problem. **However**, it will be impossible to require a comment from every downvoter, as (1) downvotes are anonymous (this is something Stack Exchange insists will not change) and (2) comments are ephemeral (again a Stack Exchange policy). Therefore, I think the better solution is to ensure, when writing a *halacha*-related post, that it is clear enough that it does not garner downvotes for the reason of sloppiness.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/146/2) is a convincing (IMO) argument from SE staff in favor of voting being available as an independent mechanism from commenting.

Comment: An additional benefit of the alternative solution you propose is that it enhances the glory of the Torah by communicating its teachings in a way that's more pleasant to the eye and more understandable to the mind.